# How to add my own module to dask worker env to avoid no module named

Tags: python, dask

I use dask clusters to process dataset. My dask python project structure is as follows:

```
project_name/
  folder_a
    a.py
  folder_b
    b.py
```

I import function `function_a()` within `a.py` in `b.py` like follows:

```
from folder_a.a import function_a

@delayed
def test(input_str):
  return function_a(input_str)

client = ...

d_task = [test(str)]
dask.compute(d_task)
```

However, dask worker nodes throw exception `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder_a'`

I have tried many solutions like add `PYTHONPATH={dir}/project_name` while none of them are available.

How to solve this problem? Is there any way that can add `{dir}/project_name` to dask worker environment?

Comment: Please see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39977635/dask-no-module-named-xxxx-error/69981627#69981627

Answer (score 0):

You did not say which scheduler you were using, but perhaps the new doc that [I just wrote](https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/6778) will help you sort out import issues: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/environment.html

Comment: I have read the docs, I can understand what you mean, but I still can not find the solution. I run `dask-sheduler` on one machine and `dask-worker IP:8786` on other machines. The python projects is stored at /home/dufei/data/project_name where /home/dufei/data is a NFS path. I know I should tell dask-worker that all packages in project_name is needed and should be appended on worker env. While upload_file is the only way I can find that could be used to solve this. However, it can not upload folder. And I can't package my folder_a into a whl since I have some related py files in other folders

Comment: If all the client and workers can see the same file system, then you can include the path you need in your PYTHONPATH. Generally, you *should* be able to make a set of packages out of all of your code, with appropriate dependencies declared.

Comment: I have tried to set PYTHONPATH on my .bashrc and use sys.path.append(project_name) in my own py file. However, it doesn't work.

Comment: You should verify the value of `sys.path` seen by your workers (`client.run(lambda: sys.path)`). You may instead want to sym-link your directory into one of the module search paths.

Comment: @mdurant your documentation doesn't show how to manage sys path on worker. My main script has imports in the top of the file that refers to my custom modules, it already fails for importing those before coming to `client.submit`